# Why does reading from stdin vary in some programs?

Tags: pipe, tty, stdin

I'm developing a program in ncurses that will read from stdin, however, while checking how some other programs do this, I noticed that it's not consistent. For instance, the following two work fine

```
tail file.txt | cat
tail file.txt | cat -
```

While these **won't** work unless I use `-`:

```
cat file.txt | vim
cat file.txt | file
```

Is there a reason why some programs allow piping data without `-` and some don't? Should they support both ways?

Comment: It likely depends on whether the program in question is normally expected to work in  pipe.  Both `vim` and `file` do not normally participate in pipes.  So you need to ask yourself,  is my program expected to live in a pipe, or not?

Comment: That makes sense and probably answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs that are meant to act as *stream filters*, taking data from some input source and progressively processing it and producing output, normally read from standard input when invoked with no non-option arguments. So for example `cat`, `tail`, etc. read from standard input by default. Tools like `grep`, `sed`, etc. require one operand (the regexp for grep, the script for sed) and read from standard input if that's the sole operand. Vi(m) does not fit this mold: it's an interactive program, not a stream filter, so it starts in interactive mode when you pass no argument.

`file` is an exception: it doesn't read from stdin unless stdin is given as an argument (possibly through the syntax `-`). I don't know why neither the original author nor the POSIX committee decided that it wouldn't read from stdin. This may be because `file` cares not only about file contents, but also about file types — `file foo` reports whether `foo` is a directory, a regular file, a symbolic link, etc. So it isn't quite a stream filter like the others, even though it's usually used as such. It's halfway between `grep` (a stream filter) and `ls` (which cares only about the file as a directory entry and not at all about the file contents).

(`grep -r` does care about file types as well, but that's an addition that came much later than the original command.)